# Retornar coluna especifica com a biblioteca csv

Tags: python, csv

Tenho uma planilha com 4 colunas e 2 linhas e quero retornar a coluna idade, sem o identificador da coluna, somente o conteúdo das linhas.

Código:

```
import csv
def get_column_of_csv(filename, column):
  with open(filename) as stream:
    reader = csv.DictReader(stream)
    for row in reader:
      yield row[column]

for name in get_column_of_csv('teste.csv', 'sobrenome'):
    print(name)
```

Ao rodar o código, exibe esse erro:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File ... line 3, in 
> from asyncore import file_wrapper
> ImportError: cannot import name 'file_wrapper' from 'asyncore' ...
> Alguém sabe como resolver esse erro?

Answer (score 0):

Usando este aquivo de referência como `teste.csv`:

```
    nome,sobrenome,idade,peso
    Maria,joao,20,60
    Joao,maria,10,30
```

Seu código funciona normalmente, retornando a coluna do **sobrenome**.

```
    import csv
    
    def get_column_of_csv(filename, column):
        with open(filename) as stream:
            reader = csv.DictReader(stream)
            for row in reader:
                yield row[column]

    for name in get_column_of_csv('teste.csv', 'sobrenome'):
        print(name)
```

Sugiro verificar sua indentação.

Em sua pergunta vocẽ mencionou que deseja exibir a **idade**, então basta alterar o critério de seleção para idade:

```
    for idade in get_column_of_csv('teste.csv', 'idade'):
        print(idade)
```